# A different kind of divisor sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Define, for a number $n$ the function $\mathcal{T}(n)$ which equals the number of *different* sums $d_1 + d_2,$ where $d_{1, 2}$ are divisors of $n.$ Now, one assumes that $\mathcal{T}(n)$ is approximately $\tau^2(n)/2$ for most $n$ but is there any analytic machinery to analyse the average/maximal behavior of something like this?

Comment: There is something to try at least. Normally (or at least often), the set $D_n$ of all divisors of $n$ should have a large multiplicative energy. Then its additive energy should be small, and as a result, its sumset $2D_n$ should be large. It is not clear to me though whether this idea can be eventually converted into reasonable estimates.

Answer (score 5):

The sequence $1, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9, 3, 10, 6, 10, 3, 16, 3, 10, \ldots$ does not seem to be in the OEIS yet.  That may be about to change...

Plotting $T(n)$ against $\tau(n)^2/2$ for $n \le 20000$, I get

[image]

which doesn't appear to support your conjecture.

EDIT:

Some more data points: the medians of $T(n)/\tau(n)^2$ for 
$n$ in the intervals $[2^d, 2^{d+1})$ for $d = 1, \ldots, 19$ are

$$ \frac{3}{4},\; \frac{17}{24},\; \frac{5}{8},\; \frac{5}{8},\; \frac{5}{8},\; \frac{5}{8},\; \frac{7}{12},\; \frac{7}{12},\; \frac{7}{12},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16},\; \frac{9}{16}
$$

Well, maybe the limit is in fact $1/2$, it's hard to say.  But it looks like my graph above may be misleading, overemphasizing those $n$ that have unusually large numbers of divisors, and these may have unusually small $T(n)/\tau(n)^2$.

EDIT: The sequence is now in the OEIS as [A260152](https://oeis.org/A260152).

Comment: Interesting! What is *your* conjecture? Since $\tau(n)$ has average order $\log n,$ would you guess $\log^2 n/\log\log n?$ for $\mathcal{T}?$

Comment: I think your initial recording of the sequence got cut off, since it ends with a $1$ (which won't be the case for any $n > 1$). Also, any prime $p$ will have only divisors $1$ and $p$ hence only sums $2$, $1+p$, and $2p$; in particular, the sequence will record a $3$ at the primes. To this end, I wonder whether considering the sequence for $n$ composite could be helpful? (Though one could similarly argue that $p^2$ a squared prime will only have sums $2$, $1+p$, $1+p^2$, $2p$, $p+p^2$, and $2p^2$, which are distinct, and thus explain the $6$ that arises for your fourth and ninth entries...)

Comment: Sorry, that last $1$ should have been a $10$.  I edited.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can try to use to get estimates for $\mathcal T$ is bounds for the number of divisors $2^k\leq d\leq 2^{k+1}$. Since pairs of divisors from different dyadic ranges have distinct sums, you can get a rough idea for a lower bound of $\mathcal T$.

The maximum $$\Delta(n)=\max_{k}|\{d|n:2^k\leq d\leq 2^{k+1}\}|$$ has been estimated by Hooley [On a new technique and its application to the theory of numbers, 1977] - something like $$\sum_{n\leq x}\Delta(n)\ll x(\log x)^{4/\pi-1}.$$ Thus, the typical number $n$ has $\Delta(n)=O((\log x)^{4/\pi-1})$ and so has about $(\log n)^{2/3}$ divisors with each from distinct dyadic ranges. Any pair of such divisors has a distinct sum so you get $\mathcal T(n)\gg (\log n)^{4/3}$. This is some way away from your conjecture however...

Comment: Although not incredibly far away, since the typical number has $(\log n)^{2\log2+o(1)}$ pairs of divisors, and $2\log2\approx1.3863$.